# What LED form factor is this?

Tags: led, standard

I see many LEDs for sale using this size:

[image]

What form factor is this? I want to buy empty enclosures to place some LEDs that I purchased into. I assume that their are enclosures available because so many LEDs are this standard size/shape.

Answer (score 2):

Get the datasheet, and it should tell you exactly where the mounting holes are, how far the body extends, etc.  I wouldn't assume this is a "standard" package without checking the datasheets of other companies.  This may be only a common package within the product line of a single company.  Of course sometimes different companies create drop in replacements for their competitor's products, but you have to check yourself.  Even if one company claims to have a drop in replacement for another's product, I'd check the datasheet too be sure how equal the two parts really are, including mechanical issues.

Comment: It seems that this may be the case - not an actual standard but multiple companies creating drop in replacements for stuff. All of the data sheets that I can find show the same dimensions, but no mention of a specific form factor.  Any idea on how to search for a compatible housing? Whenever I search I get ones that come with LEDs/drivers preinstalled. While I could always swap them out, this raises the cost of my project.